# What are these loops above the tracks at each AirTrain station for?

Tags: train

[image]
[image: Loop]

They seem to be made of plastic conduit. Maybe some sort of inductive sensor that makes 100% sure there is actually a big metal car present before allowing the doors to open?

Comment: I was first thinking sprinkler system, but that does not go well with plastic.

Comment: Part of TPWS-like system? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_Protection_%26_Warning_System

Comment: Alignment beacons for the doors?

Answer (score 0):

The shape and position certainly suggests a magnetic antenna, or really just one half of a low-power transformer, with the matching counterpart on the top of the train.

Inferring from the use case: might be a simple way of exchanging data with the train; it's probably going to be rather low-bandwidth (seeing that the carrier frequency couldn't be high and loops are inherently relatively narrow), so low-rate, but probably enough to exchange a short audio sample and maybe time information in the station, or to transmit "train speaker grade" live audio.

It all reminds me of the [inductive wireless audio systems for hearing aids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_induction_loop).